# Can MVC Model 2 Web App be faster in performance than Model1 web App?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc

We are revamping one of our product which was previously designed & coded following 'MVC Model 1'. We have developed the new Product following 'MVC Model 2' architecture and have used Spring as Framework.

I have used `JSP`, `JS`, `JQuery`, `Ajax`, `Spring JDBC` and `DB2`.

But when compared to previous 'MVC Model 1 web app', We are seeing less performance. By performance I mean navigational speed and data display on JSP. 
I have used `JMeter` to monitor the performance.

Can some one tell - Can we have 'Model 2' Webapp with higher performance compared to 'Model 1'? I know following 'Model 2' we have many other advantages like decoupling, scaling etc.
Also what all we can do to improve the performance of an Spring web App?

Answer (score 1):

MVC Model 1 was using Servlet/JSP only , Model 2 as you have mentioned is using Spring Framework so it has added few more layers in code and so i feel MVC 1 will be faster in same application/Product.

You can also look at [Web Framework Benchmarks](http://www.techempower.com/benchmarks/) , it has given comparisons between frameworks

It has 90 frameworks and various test scenario's on i7/EC2 hardware.